# Not able to get proper filepath using ActiveDocument.Path

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a Word-Plugin, at one place i am retrieving the complete path of the activedocument using ActiveDocument.Path.

A word file is opened from Lotus Notes, and I am getting the path as " C:/DOCUME~1/GEN127~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/notes80BDBD/some-file".

Why am i getting those "`" signs, for a normal file opened from Desktop or locally, it is showing proper path.

What is going wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It shows the short path instead of the long path.
It might be because Office uses old DOS-style paths.

Here's a short article on how to convert it to normal long path:
http://csharparticles.blogspot.com/2005/07/long-and-short-file-name-conversion-in.html